# What does finishing the Dead Island DLC unlock?

Tags: zombie-frontier-3

An update for ZF3 in June opened a new set of "Dead Island" DLC missions.  What do finishing these missions unlock?  Can any of the items used in the DLC be used in the main missions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to finish the Dead Island DLC last night.  The last mission is a pseudo-boss level where you need to take down a Steel Zombie.  The reward is 5 gems (similar to the previous mission), and there is no replay reward or any main reward for finishing all 50 missions in the DLC.  What a waste...

Click the images to view higher resolution versions.

Mission 50 before completing the level:

[image: Mission 50]

Mission 50 after completing the level:

[image: Mission 50 Complete]